# How to make mongo properly run my javascript script

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm trying to update my document named "things" running  javascript script from mongo shell. When I explicitly say which field to update it works like a charm but I'm having problem when I'm trying to read field name from the array.

This is my code:

```
var continuousWithMissingValues = ["A2","A14"];
var categoricWithMissingValues = ["A1", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7"];

for (var i = 0; i < continuousWithMissingValues.length; i++){

// db.things.update({A2: "?" },{$set: {A2: -1 }},  { multi : true }); this line is working properly
db.things.update({continuousWithMissingValues[i]: "?" },{$set: {continuousWithMissingValues[i]: -1 }}); //if I try to update while reading values from the array I'm getting error

print('Updated missing values for'+ continuousWithMissingValues[i]);
}
```

I have also tried using this line without any luck(this does not produce error but it doesn't update anything):

```
db.things.update({"continuousWithMissingValues.i": "?" },{$set: {"continuousWithMissingValues.i": -1 }});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mongo shell doesn't support [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names), so you have to build up your query and update objects in a few steps:

```
var query = {};
query[continuousWithMissingValues[i]] = "?";
var update = {$set: {}};
update.$set[continuousWithMissingValues[i]] = -1;
db.things.update(query, update);
```

Comment: Hi, with this code I'm not getting any errors but, values are still not updating. Any ideas why it wouldn't work?

Comment: @hunter1 Do you understand what the code is doing? If it's not updating as you expect, you need to make sure the `query` and `update` objects are end up as you need them, but that's really a separate question.

Comment: Hi, could you please throw in a link to the documentation where this is listed, because I'm obviously doing something wrong, and I can't find this syntax anywhere. Some resources would be helpfull